SplideJS pagination bullets multiplying when reopening modal which contains them
I'm running into a curious issue with SplideJS v4 + Bootstrap v4 combo.
The modal which holds the gallery is loaded remotely (via AJAX), and then populated with image links. Once that's done, SplideJS gallery is initiated.
shown.bs.modal and hidden.bs.modal are used to reinitialize the SplideJS gallery and to completely clear the contents of the modal content holder, respectively.
While that's working for the images and the gallery, the pagination bullets seem to have some strange persistence.
When you run the following code, open and close the modal a couple of times - you should see that every time a new set of X bullets is added (X being the number of images in the gallery).


var slider = "";
const imgArr = [
  "https://placehold.co/600x400/FFF/ABC123",
  "https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/456789",
  "https://placehold.co/600x400/FAA/0ABCDE",
  "https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/31343C"
];
const imgUrl = "https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/31343C";

let splideHtml = "";
let startIndex = 0;
let modalContents = `
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="splideHolder" class="splide">
          <div class="splide__track">
            <ul class="splide__list"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

$("button.openModal").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $("#previewModal").html(modalContents);
  $("#previewModal").modal({
    backdrop:"static",
    show:true
  });
});

$("#previewModal").on("shown.bs.modal",function(){
  imgArr.forEach(function(item,index) {
    let childUrl = item;

    if(childUrl === imgUrl) {
      startIndex = index;
    }

    let imgGallery = $("div.imgGallery");
    splideHtml += `
      <li class="splide__slide" style="width:600px">
        <img src="${childUrl}" alt="img${index}">
      </li>
    `;

  });

  if(splideHtml) {
    $("ul.splide__list").html(splideHtml);
    const options = {
      autoPlay  : false,
      autoWidth : true,
      focus     : 'center',
      perPage   : 1,
      perMove   : 1,
      start     : startIndex,
      trimSpace : false,
      type      : 'loop',
    };

    slider = new Splide("#splideHolder",options).mount();
  }
});

$("#previewModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function() {
  // Both of these fail
  slider.destroy("completely");
  slider = "";
  $("#previewModal").html("");
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/css/splide.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="openModal btn btn-primary">Launch demo modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="previewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>



Thinking that something is perhaps kept inside localStorage or cookies, I checked those as well, but they are completely empty.
Also, type: 'loop' doesn't seem to be the cause of it. When I change the type to slide, the multiplication still happens
Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve it?
